# NoMethodError ransack after upgrading to Rails 5 and Mongoid 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, ransack

After upgrading to Rails 5 and Mongoid 7 my Ransack is not visible for classes. For example for code:

```
users = User.ransack(params[:q])
render json: users
```

application crashes with error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `ransack' for User:Class)
```

Everything works fine on Rails 4.2 and Mongoid 4.

Current Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.5.1'
gem 'rails', '5.2.0'
gem 'ransack', git: 'https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack', require: 'mongoid' (version 1.8.8)
gem 'mongoid', '~>7' (version 7.0.1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It does not appear Ransack supports mongoid 7.  According to the read me it has limited support for 4 and 5.   This is confirmed by the changelog and gem file.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Do you recommend any alternative for Ransack that can cooperate with Mongoid 6 or 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the solution was to add

```
gem 'ransack-mongoid', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack-mongoid'
```

to the Gemfile. It is not maintained and might be discontinued in the future, as maintainer is searched for.

It adds the support for mongoid again. But, I'm unable to select any data, getting

```
User.ransack().result throws

Mongoid::Errors::CriteriaArgumentRequired - message:
  Calling Criteria methods with nil arguments is not allowed.
summary:
  Arguments to Criteria methods cannot be nil, and most Criteria methods require at least one argument. Only logical operations (and, or, nor and not), `all' and `where' can be called without arguments. The method that was called with nil argument was: where.
resolution:
  Invoke Criteria methods with non-nil arguments or omit the respective invocations.:
```

Since I have to solve this issue as well, I'll be looking more into it.

Comment: did you find any solution to the error above? I'm running into the same problem

Comment: i'm running into the same problem too, any solution for this

Comment: Same here. Any solution?